# Send an object to another object and call first objects method

Tags: c++, object, methods

I would like to send an object A as a referenced attribute to object B, and then call object A's getter method within object B. The code below gives the error:

### myClass.cpp:11: error: passing ‘const myClass’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int myClass::getNum()’ discards qualifiers

```
    // Main file: class_method_test.cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include "myClass.h"

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    myClass objA = myClass( 2 );
    myClass objB = myClass( 3 );

    objA.calc(objB);

    cout << objA.getNum() << endl;

    objB.print();

    }
```

---

```
    // myClass.h

    #ifndef MYCLASS_H
    #define MYCLASS_H

    #include <string>

    class myClass{
        private:
            int myNum;
            std::string anyText;
        public:
            myClass();
            myClass(int);
            void calc(const myClass &);
            int getNum();
            void print();
            void setText(std::string);
            std::string getText();
    };

    #endif
```

---

```
    // myClass.cpp

    #include <iostream>
    #include "myClass.h"

    using namespace std;

    myClass :: myClass() : myNum(0) {};
    myClass :: myClass ( int aNum ) : myNum( aNum ) {};

    void myClass :: calc( const myClass & calcObj )
    {
        myNum += calcObj.getNum();
    };

    int myClass :: getNum()
    {
        return myNum;
    };

    void myClass :: print ()
    {
        cout << myNum << endl;
    };

    void myClass :: setText(std::string newText) {
    anyText = newText;

    }

    string myClass :: getText() {
    return anyText;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make `getNum()` a `const` method:

```
int getNum() const;
//           ^^^^^
```

This is because `calc()` takes a `const` reference to `myClass`, so only `const` methods can be called on that reference.

```
void calc(const myClass &);
//        ^^^^^
```

Looking at the implementation of `getNum()`, there is no reason for it not to be `const` anyway.